# Occasionally incomplete response from HTTP request

Tags: lua, luasocket

I'm downloading quite big JSON data with `luasocket` (`request`), but sometimes, data are incomplete. There is no pattern, if X runs, I have Y fails and Z successful downloads. My downloading code looks like this:

```
local response = {}
local one, code, headers, status = https.request {
    url = url,
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(response)
}
```

And btw, everytime it fails on character 3615. Where is the problem and how to fix it? Is it issue in my code, luasocket, or server?

Comment: Have you tried to decompress/ compress the data?

Comment: How it should help when I'm having problem with downloading incomplete data from 3rd party server?

Comment: Capture the network traffic from the failures. See what's actually happening. If it is *always* failing at exactly the same place then something is doing it. Either a network device killing the connection or something else that is happening at the same spot every time.